# Converting a Makefile project to Cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I'm learning how to use cmake for this class but the documentation is extremely verbose and dense. A lot of the tutorials are either too simple to be useful (cmake with just one file) or too complicated.

the original Makefile for the project looks like:

```
# Some optimization settings
# see: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

# Standard all target
all: hw1_p2

# Simple program to do brute-force k-nearest neighbor searches against a signature file
hw1_p2: prob2.o ParseRecord.o Sorter.o Timing.o
        g++ -o hw1_p2 prob2.o ParseRecord.o Sorter.o Timing.o

prob2.o: prob2.cpp utility_templates.hpp
        g++ -Wall -c prob2.cpp

ParseRecord.o: ParseRecord.cpp ParseRecord.hpp utility_templates.hpp
        g++ -Wall -c ParseRecord.cpp

Sorter.o: Sorter.cpp Sorter.hpp
        g++ -Wall -c Sorter.cpp

# Timing class
Timing.o: Timing.hpp Timing.cpp
        g++ -Wall -c Timing.cpp

# Clean code-derived files
clean:
        rm -f *.o hw1_p2
```

The project is organized like this

- cmakelearn

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - build
  - src

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - ParseRecord.hpp
    - Timing.cpp
    - small.dat
    - Makefile
    - Sorter.cpp
    - Timing.hpp
    - utility_templates.hpp
    - ParseRecord.cpp
    - Sorter.hpp
    - prob2.cpp

So far, from the reading that I've done I understand that you need a CMakelists.txt file in every directory. 
The build folder is there so that I can go into it and run cmake ..

In the top-level CMakelists.txt file I have

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (CMAKETEST)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

and in the src dir CMakelist.txt here is my attempt:

```
include_directories(${CMAKETEST_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
link_directories(${CMAKETEST_BINARY_DIR}/src)

add_executable(hw1_p2 prob2.cpp ParseRecord.cpp Sorter.cpp Timing.cpp)
```

I don't even really know where to begin other than that. 
This comment from a tutorial pretty much sums up my thoughts about cmake and the documentation right now:

> Not nearly detailed enough to be useful. Having said that, I don’t like CMake much
>   anyway; too many separate, arbitrary Things you Just Have to Know. At
>   least that’s my impression. Like, ‘add_definitions(-std=c99)’. Really?
>   Does that name jump out at you as how to add flags to a compiler? And
>   is ‘set(VAR a b c)’ any more intuitive than VAR=a b c or some such?
>   Beh on the article, and on CMake. Yet I know CMake is taking the
>   build-world by storm.

Still, I really want to learn and figure this out so any help that you can provide will be much appreciated and helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`add_executable`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aadd_executable) command is for building executables, but you seem to be trying to use it to build object (`.o`) files as well. Since you are only building one executable you only need one `add_executable` command:

```
add_executable(hw1_p2 prob2.cpp ParseRecord.cpp Sorter.cpp Timing.cpp)
```

Comment: thanks, made some progress but I get an error about prob2 having an <#include Timing.hpp> in it. It says the library can't be found. So I'm guessing I have to link the library with cmake somehow. I tried TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(prob2 timing.hpp) to no avail.

Comment: @HarrisonNguyen It should be `#include <Timing.hpp>` not `<#include Timing.hpp>`.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant.                                            `[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hw1_p2.dir/src/prob2.cpp.o
/Users/harrison/Documents/cmake/src/prob2.cpp:14:10: fatal error: 'scottgs/Timing.hpp' file not found
#include <scottgs/Timing.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hw1_p2.dir/src/prob2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hw1_p2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: I changed it to #include "Timing.hpp" in prob2.cpp and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 8):

You do not have to create cmakelists.txt files in every subdirectory. For a project that simple it should be enough to put everything into the toplevel cmakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (CMAKETEST C CXX)

add_executable(hw1_p2 src/prob2.cpp src/ParseRecord.cpp src/Sorter.cpp src/Timing.cpp)
```

this simple cmakelists.txt should get the job done.

Comment: Much shorter than the makefile and works for a lot of platforms at the same time.